# Configure a One-to–Zero-or-One relationship with a composite foreign key with fluent api

Tags: c#, .net, entity-framework, ef-code-first

I'm developing a C# .NET Framework 4.0 with Entity Framework 6.1.0.

I have an existing database and I have generated Code First classes with it.

These are my classes:

```
[Table("CODES")]
public partial class CODE
{
    public CODE()
    {
    }

    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
    public long ID_CODE { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    public byte CODE_LEVEL { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column("CODE", Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string CODE1 { get; set; }

    public byte? COMMISIONING_FLAG { get; set; }

    public bool? IS_TRANSMITTED { get; set; }

    public DateTime? TIMESPAN { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string USERNAME { get; set; }

    [StringLength(50)]
    public string SOURCE { get; set; }

    public virtual AGGREGATION_CHILDS AGGREGATION_CHILDS { get; set; }

    public virtual AGGREGATION AGGREGATIONS { get; set; }
}

public partial class AGGREGATION_CHILDS
{
    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 0)]
    [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
    public long ID_AGGREGATION { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 1)]
    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ID_CHILD { get; set; }

    [Key]
    [Column(Order = 2)]
    public byte CODE_LEVEL { get; set; }

    public int POSITION { get; set; }

    public virtual AGGREGATION AGGREGATION { get; set; }

    public virtual CODE CODE { get; set; }
}

[Table("AGGREGATIONS")]
public partial class AGGREGATION
{
    public AGGREGATION()
    {
        AGGREGATION_CHILDS = new HashSet<AGGREGATION_CHILDS>();
    }

    [Key]
    public long ID_AGGREGATION { get; set; }

    [StringLength(20)]
    public string ID_PARENT { get; set; }

    public byte? PARENT_LEVEL { get; set; }

    public virtual ICollection<AGGREGATION_CHILDS> AGGREGATION_CHILDS { get; set; }

    public virtual CODE CODE { get; set; }
}
```

And model:

```
public partial class MyDbContext : DbContext
{
    public MyDbContext()
        : base("name=MyDbContext")
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<AGGREGATION_CHILDS> AGGREGATION_CHILDS { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<AGGREGATION> AGGREGATIONS { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<CODE> CODES { get; set; }

    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        modelBuilder.Entity<AGGREGATION>()
            .HasMany(e => e.AGGREGATION_CHILDS)
            .WithRequired(e => e.AGGREGATION)
            .WillCascadeOnDelete(false);
    }
}
```

`CODES` primary key is `(CODE_LEVEL, CODE1)`.

I have a one-to-one relationship between `CODES` and `AGGREGATION_CHILDS`.

```
CODES.CODE1      -> AGGREGATION_CHILDS.ID_CHILD
CODES.CODE_LEVEL -> AGGREGATION_CHILDS.CODE_LEVEL
```

And another one-to-one relationship between `CODES` and `AGGREGATION`.

```
CODES.CODE1      -> AGGREGATION.ID_PARENT
CODES.CODE_LEVEL -> AGGREGATION.PARENT_LEVEL
```

But in `AGGREGATION` foreign key is optional: `ID_PARENT` and `PARENT_LEVEL` could be `NULL`.

How can I set up those both relationships on `OnModelCreating`?